# How do I get real errors with requirejs?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, requirejs

I'm new to requireJS, and I'm trying to figure out why I can't get normal errors.

I'm using this, right after the requirejs file is loaded, but before any modules are loaded:

```
requirejs.onError = function (err) {
    console.log(err.requireType);
    if (err.requireType === 'timeout') {
        console.log('modules: ' + err.requireModules);
    }

    throw err;
};
```

But I'm still getting the completley vague error:

```
Error: script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror @ http://localhost/wampir/lib/require.js:8
"scripterror"
```

Is there a way to make this give me the actual error and line number?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9032517/1074592) but I've tried several answers from there, and they don't change anything...

Comment: Their terrible error logging has bugged me for awhile.  I really don't see why it can't say something like `error loading script name blah/foo which was searched for at blah/foo.js`

Comment: Okay, I'll just use browserify.  I wanted to give requirejs a try.  Thanks

Comment: Can you and @AdamRackis elaborate on what errors you're missing? Load failures on modules themselves, or errors within the javascript of those modules? For the former, I get nice 404s in the console window, at least on latest Chrome and with RequireJS 2.1.8

Comment: @explunit, the problem is I didn't know what to be looking for.  My IDE has AST analysis and it didn't find any errors in the code, or unresolvable paths.  The RequireJS docs for "script error" say it's likely a syntax error or an uncaught error.  It's not a 404, though.  Anyway, if you want to post an answer I'll accept it.  I've gone back to Browserify and everything's working now.  I think I was missing a "new" in one of the files.

Comment: Well, this is what that error means: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Answer (score 6):

Remove the "timeout" check.  It's keeping you from seeing the modules you're having a problem with unless the problem happens to be a timeout.

```
requirejs.onError = function (err) {
    console.log(err.requireType);
    console.log('modules: ' + err.requireModules);
    throw err;
};
```