# How can I get line numbers from require.js errors?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, google-chrome-devtools

This has been bothering me for a while but I haven't been able to find a solution. When I have an error in one of my scripts, such as a syntax error, Chrome's console does not give me a very useful error message.

For example, in a simple script called `example.js` I am calling a function called `whatever()` which does not exist:

```
define(function(require){
  'use strict';

  whatever();
});
```

My console error in Chrome states:

```
ReferenceError: whatever is not defined(…)                 require.js:901
```

I expect the ReferenceError but line 901 of `require.js` is just some code responsible for throwing errors. Furthermore, the stack trace doesn't show anything useful; it also only references lines in `require.js`. I noticed that Firefox's inspector does show the actual location of the problem in the stack trace, which is helpful but I prefer to develop in Chrome.

Is there a way to make console errors point to the line number and file where the problem actually is? I would rather see:

```
ReferenceError: whatever is not defined(…)                 example.js:4
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372587/how-do-i-get-real-errors-with-requirejs) and others like it that sound similar but I haven't found any that apply to this exact situation, or code that works with requirejs to fix this issue. Maybe I can modify `requirejs.onError` somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to append

```
//# sourceURL=example.js
```

at the end of your evaluated script? Debuggers will understand that code as originating from example.js file rather then from the script it was evaluated in.

You sure that Require.JS does not support it out of the box? I posted on GitHub my own "Javascript DNA" asynchronous loader/dependency resolver that does it automatically and it was very easy so I guess require.js will have something similar already...

Comment: Doing that does force the stack trace to display the location of the error. I was hoping maybe this could be configured in require.js somehow but manually adding sourcemaps seems to be a decent workaround.

Comment: Oh, also, this particular error handling seems to be particular to require.js, as the console error is pointing to this line: `console.error(err);` which seems to be explicitly returning a new error instead of allowing the original one to show