# Is there a way to conditional load a module via RequireJS based on whether or not the module 404s?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Problem:
We currently have the following require.config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        lodash: '/embed/lodash',
        utils: '/embed/utils',
        analytics: '/external/analytics'
    }
});
```

file paths that start with `embed` are guaranteed to exist.
file paths that start with `external` may or may not be available, depending on the environment.
If I begin my main.js with the following:

```
require(['lodash', 'utils', 'analytics'], function (_, utils, analytics) {
```

and analytics can't be found, the whole thing crashes (as expected).
Trying variations on the following proved fruitless:

```
require(['lodash', 'utils'], function (_, utils) {
    ...code and stuff
    $.ajax({ url: '/path/to/actual/file' })
        .done(function () {
            require(['analytics'], function (analytics) {
                // throws Mismatched anonymous define() module Error
            });
        })
        .fail(function () {
            // continue with stub of analytics
            // or not run analytics dependent code
        });
```

As per the title of this question:
Is there a way to conditionally include a module in RequireJS based on whether or not the file is accessible?

Comment: What do u exactly want to do when there is 404 for analytics? U dont want to load fallback as per your comment, so please elaborate about what exactly u want...

Comment: When the analytics 404s, the app should not crash, so the answer to your question is - when analytics 404s, I don't want to do anything with analytics for the rest of the execution.

Comment: So u have analytics code like analytics.send(), which u dont care about if in local, in that case u can supply the object with the methods that u use from analytics in the fallback.

Comment: Updated the answer to depict replacing analytics...

Comment: apologies, but my coworker informed me that I should have read the crappy documentation of RequireJS, and proceeded to give me the correct solution to my problem.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching module loading errors and processing them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032517/catching-module-loading-errors-and-processing-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my colleague, who provided the correct solution to my problem, and kindly told me to RTFM: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks

Keeping "normal" declaration of require.config, just add an error callback to handle the case when the module can't be found.

```
require(['lodash', 'utils'], function (_, utils) {
    ...code and stuff
    require(['analytics'], function (analytics) {
        // normal execution

    }, function (error) {
        // continue with stub of analytics
        // or not run analytics dependent code at all

    });
```

Comment: not to be a pedant, but conditionally require usually means 0 or 1, not 1 or another 1, so no, a fallback file was never really an option to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

If you want fallback to be downloaded when your external file is not available, you can use [path fallback](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks) configuration in requireJS.

Set your path configuration like following.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        lodash: '/embed/lodash',
        utils: '/embed/utils',
        analytics: ['/external/analytics',
                     '/embed/analytics'
                ]
    }
});
```

Then create a file analytics.js in embed directory which gives you the object normally returned by analytics from outside. If external/analytics adds a object in the global namespace, do that as well.

**embed/analytics.js**

```
define(function(){
    var analytics = window.analytics = {
        send : function(){
            //Nothing to do here.
        }
        //,... //Add more methods used by your code like send
    }
    return analytics;
});
```

Comment: Your answer assumes that there's actually a backup to pull the script from.  This is not the case, and the code is full prepared to do something else in the absence of a library.

Comment: I thought so, that's why I started my answer with if.

Comment: Will try to find what you want.