# How to avoid can't find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `reactjs` script which use `.jpg`

However jpg filename is dynamically changed.

```
const img_require = require(id + ".jpg");
```

it works well when file exists, but when there is not file,

throwing error like this below

```
Error: Cannot find module './12.jpg'
```

I want to avoid this error message and use `dummy.jpg`.

But this code doesn't work on browser side(of course)

```
fs = require('fs')

if (fs.exitsSync('./12.jpg')){
// ok
}else {
    const img_require = 'dummy.jpg';
}
```

Is there any idea??

Comment: What is the value of `id` when file deons't exist? `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use try-catch block for require file like this : 
I am not expert in react but this might be basic hack .

```
var fs;

try {
   fs =  require(id + ".jpg")
} catch (error) {
   fs =  require("dummy.jpg")
}
```

One more way to handle error that is provided by `require.js` using [ErrorCallback](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks)

here is the fallback answer for module load.

[Catching module loading errors and processing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032517/catching-module-loading-errors-and-processing-them)

```
require([path], function(content){
//need to catch errors as this will not be called;
}, function (err) {
  //display error to user
});
```

Comment: try and catch works well for my purpose and it is the most simple answer. thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
const dynamicid = id || 'dummy' 

const img_require = require(`${dynamicid} + .jpg`);
```

Comment: This might only work if `id` is null or undefined.  can't load module if `id` is there but module not found in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dynamicId = id ? id : 'dummy' 

var img = require(`${dynamicId} + .jpg`);
```